# How to regenerate metadata/tables.yaml in Hasura

Tags: hasura

I am working with [merging `master` into a branch that was made some time ago](https://github.com/MetaFam/TheGame/pull/225). It created a Hasura migration and then several more were added in `master`.

There are now [merge conflicts in `metadata/tables.yaml`](https://github.com/MetaFam/TheGame/pull/225). `tables.yaml` is generated and maintained by Hasura, correct?

Hasura won't start with the conflicted `tables.yaml`. I replaced it with one from `hasura init` and was able to remove the Docker images (`docker-compose down -v`) and recreate them (`docker-compose up --build -d`).

When I run `hasura migrate status` it shows all the migrations as run, but the contents of `metadata/tables.yaml` hasn't changed.

How do I regenerate that file?

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is `hasura metadata export`. I tried this initially and the command generated an empty array (`[]`). It turns out this is because I replaced the `tables.yaml` with an empty set in order to get Hasura to start.

After running `hasura console`, rewatching the tables, and resetting the permissions; the `metadata export` command worked as expected and regenerated `tables.yaml`.